# VBA Word Find/Paragraph Copy

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Current I am trying to open a word document, look for a certain word (in this case "Description") then go two lines below and copy the paragraph under it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub getTextFromWord()

Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object

file = "C:\filepath\Document.docx"
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = False
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(file)

With Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = "Description"
    .Execute
End With

'Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
'Selection.StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
'Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph
'Selection.Copy
'Range("A1").PasteSpecial

WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I try to run it (with the current Selection.MoveDown part commented out) either I get a 450 error or a pop-up from Excel saying "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The format of the document I am trying to copy from is essentially:

Date: July 09, 2015

Description

This is the general description. Today is July 09, 2015 and this is my general description etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, and I may be incorrect on this, that you can simply suppress the alert and the code will finish on it's own.

To do that, add
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the beginning of the subroutine.

Don't forget to add
`Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end of the subroutine to turn it back on.

It seems this message appears when Excel passes control to Word and doesn't get a response soon enough, but I *believe* the code should still execute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joshua, it seems as though the program just runs indefinitely when I do this however.